# Transfer files older than N days with WinSCP

Tags: windows, date, winscp

How to transfer files with WinSCP that are older than N days? It seems there is no such option inside. But could it be done with scripting/cmd mix?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [file mask with a time constraint](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time):

- Upload:

  ```
  put C:\local\path\*.*<5D /remote/path/
  ```
- Download:

  ```
  get /remote/path/*.*<5D C:\local\path\
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`find` can find the files you're interested in, and `rsync` can take the resultant list and process it.

Comment: this question about WinSCP taht is Windows application.. your answer about *nix tools. PS: i know that rsync exist for windows, but winscp work not only with sftp.

Comment: `find` is also available for Windows. http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/